# Sitecore 8.1 with SQL Always ON

Tags: sql-database

I know Sitecore 8.1 is not compatible with SQL Always ON as per Sitecore documentation. That is a feature released with 8.2.

But, would anybody know why specifically it wouldn`t work?

Thank you

Comment: No one has claimed it wouldn't work. Just that it's not supported. In general, Azure support in Sitecore happened from 8.2 and onwards.

Comment: right, I am not aware of any problem either, I am looking for someone who actually had a problem by trying to set up such configuration.
The 8.2 release includes always on as a new feature, I am wondering there might be something in 8.1 that is incompatible.

Comment: I used this setup in 7.2 and 8.0 and it was working just fine, never ran into any issues with it. Make sure you connect to the listener so automatic failover will work. If this is in Azure also make sure you configure the retryer.